# Calling a Bash function with an argument that has an ampersand in it

Tags: bash, aria2

I want a bash function that turns this …

```
download HELLO&P=1&Q=2
```

into this …

```
aria2c -d ~/Downloads "HELLO&P=1&Q=2"
```

`HELLO&P=1&Q=2` is a MAGNET link. If it doesn’t have double quotes around it, aria2c doesn’t work. But I can’t seem to keep it all together. The problem  seems to be that the MAGNET link has series of `&key=value` pairs at the end (in my example `&P=1&Q=2`) and these seem to be getting stripped out and separated from the rest of the link (i.e. `HELLO`).

Here is my `.bash_profile` function.

```
download() {
  aria2c -d ~/Downloads "$1"
}
```

Here are is a sample output.

```
~ $ download HELLO&P=1&Q=2
[1] 7389
[2] 7390
aria2c -d /Users/lukejanicke/Downloads HELLO
[1]-  Done                    download HELLO
[2]+  Done                    P=1
~ $
```

No even sure where `Q=2` went. With real MAGNET links, all the parts are displayed in this enumerated way.

I need some way of capturing the whole MAGNET link as a single parameter and then executing the `aria2c` command with quotes around the link.

Comment: Re: "where Q=2 went" -- it was executed (in the foreground, vs `P=1` happening in the background in a subshell that then exited after completion of that one-line/three-character command). If you run `echo "$Q"` in the same shell, output will be `2`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Double quotes make bash to interpret the inner string.

I've tested it with:

```
$ download() {   aria2c -d ~/Downloads "$1"; }
victor 0 12:48 /Users/victor/tmp

$ download "http://localhost:8080/HELLO&P=1&Q=2"

10/07 12:48:56 [NOTICE] Downloading 1 item(s)

10/07 12:48:56 [ERROR] CUID#7 - Download aborted. 
URI=http://localhost:8080/HELLO&P=1&Q=2E
```

Comment: Yeah, notice that when you call download, you can also use single quotes. Does this solve your question?

Comment: It’s not what I wanted but it seems to be as good as I’m going to get.

Comment: @lukejanicke, if you didn't put them around the link in the user's input, how would the shell know the user wasn't asking it to run `download HELLO` in the background, and a separate command `P=1` in the background, and a separate command `P=2` in the foreground?

Comment: My question is how to write a function that take the magnet link and puts it in quotes

Comment: So you’re saying there isn’t a way? This is just how bash works? I can live with that. I’m just learning.

Comment: You generally can't copypaste a url into the shell prompt without making it a valid shell command, but you can definitely write a command that takes a file full of URLs or that prompts you to paste a URL without requiring quotes.

Comment: @lukejanicke Yes, that's just how bash works. And not just bash, any shell that conforms to POSIX shell syntax rules. In any POSIX shell, if a command line contains an `&` that isn't either escaped or inside quotes (or part of a compound syntactic element like `>&`), it'll be parsed as a delimiter between commands rather than as part of a command or its arguments.

Answer (score 3):

`&` is a special character in the shell. You need to quote the string containing it:

```
download 'HELLO&P=1&Q=2'
```

Otherwise, it's understood as command separator that runs the left hand side in the background.